# Unknown column in where clause during join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Hi I'm working on a project that has a person model, a person has a building, a building has a building manager. I want all the people with buildings that have a certain building manager. So I have a query as follows:

```
persons.joins(:building).where(buildings: { building_manager_id: 1 } )
```

But with that I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'buildings.building_manager_id' in 'where clause'
```

I'm not sure why this is, any help would be great.

Comment: What is about `Unknown column 'buildings.building_manager_id' in 'where clause'` that you don't understand?

Comment: I understand the error, I don't understand why it's been given. Buildings does have a building_manager_id column.

Comment: Can you post the output of `to_sql`, that is append `to_sql` to the end of the statement.